# Delphi threads question - thread calling a procedure defined in the main form

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

If I have a thread calling a procedure that is defined in the main form, and that procedure calls another function from a supporting unit, and uses variables defined in the main form - is this thread-safe?  Do I need to use `Synchronize()` in the thread when calling subroutines that may access common variables?

I understand that if my thread is accessing common variables/components directly, I need to either avoid it or use `Synchronize()`, but what about those accessed indirectly, from the subroutines called by the thread code?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter from which procedure/function such variables are accessed. What matters is within which thread context those procedures/functions are executed.

All variables that are connected/coupled with UI need to be accessed within the context of the main thread.

But, any other variables that are not connected/coupled to UI can still be unsafe if accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

That is why there are so many different protection mechanisms available to prevent this.

Using [`Synchronize`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/Synchronize_(Delphi)) is the easiest way to synchronize certain code with the main thread. But other mechanisms, like [Critical Sections](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Critical_Sections), [System.TMonitor](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMonitor), etc, are usually used to prevent multiple threads from simultaneously accessing the same variable/object.

Comment: Thank you. If a variable is defined in a public section of the main form (vcl), is this what you meant by "connected/coupled"?  I could have that variable defined in the main program unit but not in the main form. Would it make it safer for different threads to access that variable?

Comment: And for "context from which they are executed".  Lets say I have a thread code that calls ProcedureA which is defined in the main form public session.  If this code is executed by 2 different threads, would it be safe to call ProcedureA from that code (and possibly executed by 2 diff threads at the same time)?  
What if ProcedureA is defined in a supporting unit, is it safe to be executed by the thread code?

Comment: I see you lack the proper understanding of multi-threading. Consider each thread as worker. Each procedure/function as specific work. Each variable as piece of paper. Now if you have multiple workers doing same work during which they are writing on the same piece of paper you will run into trouble since your workers would be interfering each other. Now if you make sure that each worker has its own pice of paper then you no longer have this problem. Similar is with code. As long as you don't have multiple threads accessing same variable you won't have any problem.

Comment: Thanks SIlverWarior, I do understand the basics of how it is supposed to work, my question was more about how the compiler actually handles it. The reason I asked was because I was thinking, what happens when a system api is called by a piece of code inside a thread? I do not know what's inside that api and whether or not it is thread-safe, I just have to assume it is. Either that, or the compiler does some magic and somehow allows thread code use the underlying api conflict-free, without me knowing the specifics

Comment: and the question regarding variables defined in the main form - I am assuming it's writing to that variable that must be protected from threads writing  to it at the same time, but reading is fine - I see no issue if the threads are reading the same variable without modifying it. Is this correct?   And from the standpoint of threads not interacting directly with VCL components - I am assuming the main form is one, so I guess I should not be accessing that variable directly from the threads. But if this variable is defined in the main program (NOT in Form1) - will this be Ok?

Comment: Whether sme API is thread safe or not depends on that specific API. Believe it or not but large portion of Windows API is not thread safe. In fact VCL itself is just and abstract layer that allows easy access to windows GDI API, which itself is not thread-safe and consequently this makes VCL not thread safe. And as I have ad before it doesn't matter where some variable is defined but how it is accessed. Don't confuse code scope with thread context as they are not the same.

Comment: In order for this to become very long discussion I strongly recommend you go and read some book regarding multi-threading since multi-threading is actually quite vast and complex concept, that can't be sufficiently discussed in comments. I personally would recommend you take a look at [Parallel Programming with OmniThreadLibrary](https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2018/02/parallel-programming-with.html)  book that was written by Primoz Gabrielcic. A large portion of what I have learned about multi-threading was by attending on of his presentation about multi-threading a few years ago. ...

Comment: ... I still haven't found the time to read through his book but based on my experience with his presentation then I'm sure it is quite good. While majority of the book focuses on using Omni Thread Library that was developed by Primoz himself I do know that the first portion of the book covers the basics of multi-threading, its advantages and its disadvantages in great detail. So I'm sure that by reading it you will probably get answer for most of your questions.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the tip about Primoz and his presentations. I found this and will be watching all his videos to get a better handle on the subject:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1ZsmnszWDU